# getting syntax error with doctrine when trying to purge my database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I keep getting this error whenever I try to load my data fixtures:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM order':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error i     n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server v     ersion for the right syntax to use near
>   'order' at line 1

Comment: Use backticks for order

Comment: As i answered use backticks around table name `order`.

Comment: i am working on Symfony 2 and that was a CMD command "php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load" so i guess i'll just rename that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `order` is reserved keyword in mysql so try like below:-

```
DELETE FROM `order`
```

Means use backticks around table name

Reference:- [MYSQL Reserve Words & Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks around table name:

```
DELETE FROM `order`
```

Becuase order is a reserve word in MYSQL

**[MYSQL Reserve Words & Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)**  check reserve words if you find **(R)** along with any word it means it's a reserve word.